# What is the difference between running an application on ec2-server and running an application on top of docker on ec2-server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, containers, dockerfile

Lets say we have a war file.
I am going to deploy it on AWS.

I can install tomcat ,etc and deploy it directly on the ec2-instance.
I can install docker and install everything in the container and deploy it.

What is the difference ?
when should I use what?

UPDATE from CryptoFool (2/22):

I'm facing this same question regarding how I will deploy my Java back-end service application. The answer I'm looking for is not here yet.

I'm a seasoned developer who has used Docker for years.  I understand the differences between the two options from the development and devops perspectives. I get what Docker does.

What I want to know is if anything is lost in terms of functionality or performance if I add Docker to the mix. Assume that my app has exclusive use of the instance.  If I configure things ideally, will my app have just as much memory available to it running under Docker?  Same for CPU...will/might my app run any slower under Docker?  How about network performance...should that be the same either way?  In other words, can I assume that my app will provide the same user experience with either approach?

Knowing what I do about what Docker is, my thinking is that there's no reason to expect any significant runtime differences between the two approaches.  Am I right?

Answer (score 4):

An EC2 instance is a virtual machine. You can do everything you want with it (and you also should do a few things like patching). The EC2 instance is based on an Amazon Machine Image (AMI).

A docker container runs on a docker host. The docker host could be an EC2 instance or your laptop. It's based on a docker image. So you still need toe docker host.

If you just want to run a war, check out ElasticBeanstalk. You can just upload the war and everything else is managed by AWS.

If you want to use Docker, you can also use Beanstalk or setup your own ECS cluster which is overkill for one app in my opinion.

Update (2/22):

ECS is another great alternative.  ECS will let you run your app in a container without you having to manage EC2 instances yourself.  It's functionally the same idea as your Docker alternative.

Comment: Yes.. Thanks for the Answer.
But whichever the one I would use the output would be the same.
When should I choose one over other?
What is the difference ? when should I use what?

Comment: that depends totally on your requirements. your only requirement was that it is a war file. and if this is your only requirement, you have many options. so you may will choose the most simple solution, cost effective, ... look at ElasticBeanstalk.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is convenience and your use case. With docker you can prepare a Dockerfile which is based on a tomcat image, add your application and configure it. Everything from your local machine. Then you can upload your docker image to the docker registry and simply run it in your ec2 instance. You don't need to create an ami to replicate you  configuration.

Regards